# How to look at BGP's LOC-RIB using Quagga library

Tags: routes, network-programming, bgp, quagga

While reading the documentation, I saw that, "You can use Quagga library as your program’s client user interface". Basically, I want to look at  BGP's  LOC-RIB (RIB = Routing Information Base) that Quagga constructs, with my C program (in Ubuntu/ FreeBSD).

I have just started using Quagga and I want to know how to do this using Quagga library (or maybe by using the *.h files that quagga provides).

Can any one help me with suggestions, tutorials or links?

Bye.

Answer (score -1):

programatically telnet into bgpd (the deamon which runs bgp) and enter "show ip bgp", then programatically read the stdout. 
Thats a crude but workable way to do it.